# Define flatten layer in neural network using pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, tensor, flatten

I'm trying to define a flatten layer before initiating fully connected layer. As my input is a tensor with shape `(512, 2, 2)`, so I want to flatten this tensor before FC layers.

I used to get this error:

```py
empty(): argument 'size' must be tuple of ints, but found element of type Flatten at pos 2
```

```py
import torch.nn as nn
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network,self).__init__()
        self.flatten=nn.Flatten()
        self.fc1=nn.Linear(self.flatten,512)
        self.fc2=nn.Linear(512,256)
        self.fc3=nn.Linear(256,3)
 
        
    def forward(self,x):
        x=self.flatten(x) # Flatten layer
        x=torch.ReLU(self.fc1(x))  
        x=torch.ReLU(self.fc2(x))
        x=torch.softmax(self.fc3(x))
        return x
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error stack trace?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is not correct:

```py
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(self.flatten, 512)
```

the first argument `in_features` for `nn.Linear` should be `int` not the `nn.Module`

in your case you defined `flatten` attribute as a `nn.Flatten` module:

```py
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
```

to fix this issue, you have to pass `in_features` equals to the number of feature after flattening:

```py
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(n_features_after_flatten, 512)
```